# How many positive integers $d$ satisfy the conditions?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

(Adapted)(Olympiad of Moldova) Let $n = 2^{13}3^{11}5^7$. If $d\mid n^2$, $d < n$ and $d \nmid n$, find how many numbers $d$ exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many divisors of $n^2$ are less than $n$? they are exactly half of one less than  the number of  divisors. (pair up $d$ and $n^2/d$, the only one with  no pair is $n$).

From these you must subtract all the proper divisors of $n$ and you have your answer. The final ingredient is the number of divisors formula which I'm sure you know.

Comment: A small correction: it should read "half of one less the sum of divisors" instead of "one less than half of the divisors." i.e. $\frac{\sigma_0(n^2)-1}{2}$ (you can check the sum of divisors is odd).

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for that :)